# Unable to get special dates of products

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I got some weird problem. I am trying to get "special_to_date" and "special_from_date" of a product but it is returning me a null value.
I tried these two methods to obtain values. But they return null values.

```
var_dump($_product["special_to_date"]);
var_dump($_product->getSpecialTODate());
```

When i do this `var_dump($_product);`. Then i get all values including special dates. 
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, i had set special price  of product in a default config scope. when i checked that product in store view level then there was no special price. 
So when i `var_dump($_product);`, it returns the special_to_date of default config scope. Also it returns special_to_date NULL in the same product so i figured out that special price is not set in store view level. I then set the special price in store view level and problem resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You have typo:

Change this

```
var_dump($_product->getSpecialTODate());
```

to

```
var_dump($_product->getSpecialToDate());
```

OR

```
echo $_product->getData('special_to_date');
```

Comment: still not working.

Comment: then try `getData`. I assume you hold **product object** in `$_product` variable.

Comment: Adarsh i have tried both methods. but it return nothing. i am successfully getting other attributes of product like name, id.

Comment: Probably you don't have anything in **Special to Date** field of that product? My guess.

Comment: You wont believe, when i var_dump($product); then it returns all special dates. when i try to get just special_to_date then it returns null

Comment: is it **$product** or **$_product**?

Answer (score 2):

use `echo $_product->getSpecialToDate();` or `$_product->getData('special_to_date');`

Comment: I tried. I dont know why it is not working. when i var_dump $_product then i have special to date and special from date. but when i try to get special dates individually then it returns null.